# PHP redirect after inserting data

Tags: php, sql

I'm having issues on redirecting to another page after inserting data.

I'm working on localhost i'm trying to redirect into another page (url) after insertin data.

With the code below, I try putting google url it doesn't redirect it stays on the page after submission.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Booking Template
 */
get_header();

require_once("db.php");

if(count($_POST)>0) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (reason, doctor, bookingDate, bookingTime, patientName, gender, phone, email) VALUES ('" . $_POST["reason"] . "','" . $_POST["doctor"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingDate"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingTime"] . "','" . $_POST["patientName"] . "','" . $_POST["gender"] . "','" . $_POST["phone"] . "','" . $_POST["email"] . "')";

  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    header("location: http://www.google.com"); 
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: add exit(); after header . example -  header("location: http://www.google.com"); exit;

Comment: Please read about SQL injections, PDO and bind parameters and proper data validation as your code above is exposed to all kinds of attack's and to answer your question your **redirect** is not happening because your **INSERT** **FAILED**

Comment: @BobbyAxe I can insert data on my database with that code above. Thanks

Comment: If so use `ob_start();` at the very top of your script

Answer (score 2):

If you echo or print something before `header()` it won't redirect. So you need to remove the `echo` before the `header()`. It is also very safe to use an `exit()` after the `header()`.

```
/**
 * Template Name: Booking Template
 */
get_header();

require_once("db.php");

if(count($_POST)>0) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (reason, doctor, bookingDate, bookingTime, patientName, gender, phone, email) VALUES ('" . $_POST["reason"] . "','" . $_POST["doctor"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingDate"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingTime"] . "','" . $_POST["patientName"] . "','" . $_POST["gender"] . "','" . $_POST["phone"] . "','" . $_POST["email"] . "')";

  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    //echo "Records inserted successfully."; remove or comment this line
    header("location: http://www.google.com");
    exit(); // use exit. It's a good practice
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

If your query is ok and data is inserting correctly but yet not redirecting and you can use `Javascript` redirecting.

```
/**
 * Template Name: Booking Template
 */
get_header();

require_once("db.php");

if(count($_POST)>0) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings (reason, doctor, bookingDate, bookingTime, patientName, gender, phone, email) VALUES ('" . $_POST["reason"] . "','" . $_POST["doctor"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingDate"] . "','" . $_POST["bookingTime"] . "','" . $_POST["patientName"] . "','" . $_POST["gender"] . "','" . $_POST["phone"] . "','" . $_POST["email"] . "')";

  if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    //echo "Records inserted successfully."; remove or comment this line
    header("location: http://www.google.com");
    echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.google.com';</script>";
    exit(); // use exit. It's a good practice
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Make sure there is no error in `get_header()` function and double check for any possible error in the code. Use this second method only if you need solve it just for now.

Comment: `exit` is important because the redirect does not end the execution of the current code "scope" so in your code it  may still do `mysqli_close($link);` even though you called header before it.  In many cases this can produce undesirable results. So +1 for including that and the warning about output.   PHP will close the connection at the end of execution, so in most cases you don't need to call `mysqli_close` anyway.

Comment: One time I saw a header redirect inside of a while loop with no exit, it did all kinds of weird things ... lol.  That was some old PHP4 code back in 2009 ish ... lol. .. it was pretty insane.  You can use output before a header call if you use output buffering `ob_start` and the other `ob_*` functions.  But it can be hard to keep track of.  It (output buffering) works wonderful with AJAX stuff too.

Comment: @Mahbubul Islam I've try still not redirecting to another page

Comment: Welcome :) @Red You can accept and up vote my answer if you like.